# Cannot upload multiple files to ftp from Android device

Tags: android, ftp

I'm using [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) library to connect to my FTP-server, which works well. And if I want to upload a file to my FTP, I'm using this code below, which also work great.

```
FileInputStream srcFileStream = new FileInputStream(mFile);
// change working directory to the destination directory
if (ftpChangeDirectory(desDirectory)) {
    status = mFTPClient.storeFile(mFile.getName(), srcFileStream);
} else {
    ftpMakeDirectory(desDirectory);
    if (ftpChangeDirectory(desDirectory))
        status = mFTPClient.storeFile(mFile.getName(), srcFileStream);
}
srcFileStream.close();
```

There is one problem thought. If I want to upload multiple files to my FTP, and I put it in a loop, it only uploads the first one, and then stops, using this code:

```
for(ImageItem mItem : mItems) {
    Log.d("test", "start" + mItems.indexOf(mItem));
    FileInputStream srcFileStream = new FileInputStream(mItem.getImageFile());

    // change working directory to the destination directory
    if (ftpChangeDirectory(desDirectory)) {
        status = mFTPClient.storeFile(mItem.getImageFile().getName(), srcFileStream);
    } else {
        ftpMakeDirectory(desDirectory);
        if(ftpChangeDirectory(desDirectory))
           status = mFTPClient.storeFile(mItem.getImageFile().getName(), srcFileStream);
    }
    srcFileStream.close();
}
```

Anyone knows how it shall be done? 
All help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance, 
Måns

Comment: Looks like you're changing the destination directory for each file you upload. Try without that.

Answer (score 0):

This ftp library work asynchronously so you can't do it in this way. It sends only the first one because the state the others will find the stream busy. You should use AsyncTask and isert your "for" in the function of doInBackground(String... args)